# CMake cannot locate Swift compiler in macOS Ventura

Tags: swift, macos, cmake

I’m working on macOS and have updated my OS version recently. When I try to build Swift based library generated from cmake, I fail on the following line:

```
enable_language(Swift)
```

It looks like the compiler couldn’t be found (although I’ve properly installed Xcode+developer tools). Here’s the relevant output:

```
-- The Swift compiler identification is unknown
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/me/myProj/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/me/myProj/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (enable_language):
No CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER could be found
```

Here’s my Swift compiler location:

```
❯ xcrun swift -version
Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
❯ xcrun --find swift
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift
```

Perhaps there’s a way to explicitly set the compiler pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the `CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER`

```
set(CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER /path/to/swift)
```

in this case

```
set(CMAKE_Swift_COMPILER /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift)
```